# Один 301 редирект вместо 3х последовательных в.htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Есть файлик .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.ru/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ https://example.ru/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Подскажите, как можно поправить редирект со страниц с слэшами в конце, он должен быть один, а сейчас происходит три последовательных:
Пример: с https://example.ru/page//// на https://example.ru/page/

Сейчас же судя по https://bertal.ru просиходит так:
1. http://www.example.ru/page///
2. https://www.example.ru/page/
3. https://example.ru/page/

Нужно, чтобы сразу на третий вариант.
Пожалуйста, очень нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([^.]*[^/])$ https://example.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  " /index\.(php|htm)"
    RewriteRule ^index\.(php|htm) https://example.ru/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}       !=on     [OR]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^?]+// [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.   [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```